# I cannot screenshot using Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, screenshot

When I was using Windows 8, I used <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> to quickly screenshot and save in my screenshot folder, but now in Windows 10 when I press the combination the screenshot doesn't save.

I have checked my clipboard and nothing.  I have also tried just <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> and it didn't or copy to my clipboard.  I can use [Snipping Tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snipping_Tool), but that is difficult because some of the things I try to screenshot disappear when you click off of it (like context menus and stuff).  I have also gone through multiple tutorials on how to fix it through the Registry Editor, but they never work since my registry seems fine.  Is there any reason Windows 10 won't let me screenshot?

Comment: They keyboard shortcut you were using, has not changed, and it still works for me.  Make sure your function mode is enabled/disabled because it should work, I am basically saying, your problem is caused by user error.  Please don't try to fix the registry when there isn't anything wrong with it, I have seen more people mess up their registry, trying to manually solve a problem within it that wasn't even an issue.

Comment: @Ramhound I haven't changed anything in the registry I only looked at it to make sure it looked fine

Comment: Have you tried a different keyboard just to rule out a faulty button

Comment: @Harvey no I have not, because I don't have a different keyboard to use.  But when I press `PrtSc` the Dropbox image saver pops up (until I disabled the Dropbox image saver), and the `Win` button works because it opens up the start menu.

Comment: Since the beginning of times, taking a *clipboard* screenshot in Windows was done through either `PrintScreen` button (whole screen) or `Alt + PrintScreen` combination (just the active window). Why are you pressing `Win + PrintScreen`? In Windows 10 this combination saves the screenshot to a file, not to clipboard.

Comment: @AnT because I want it saved as a file, and a lot of webpages I visited said to check if it is your clipboard.  So to make sure people didn't just answer saying `"check your clipboard"`, I ruled out that possibility in the question.

Comment: Re *"some of the things I try to screenshot disappear when you click off of it (like context menus and stuff)"*: That requires a tool that, when activated, [delays the screen copy action to let you have enough time to activate the context menu](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2021/09/10/taking-a-screenshot-of-a-menu-in-cinnamon-linux/) (or other menus, etc.), say for 10 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check in sub-folders of "Pictures".

I found my "Screenshots" folder inside a sub-folder.

Another idea: right click in the screenshots folder you said you have (From Windows 8) and click properties. If you see a tab called "Location" - that means that that is your screenshots folder now as well. You can change it or "restore default". Maybe that will fix it.

And yet another possible problem: Some computers have two modes for their function keys - one when the `fn` key is pressed, and one for when it's not pressed. You can try pressing `Win + fn + PrtSc` and see if that works. (And of course rebooting solves some problem too.)

**For anybody looking for a solution for this** - Changing the `Location` of the folder was the solution as the OP mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I go to `Pictures\Screenshots` and I get all my screenshots from when I was using Windows 8

Comment: @Jaketr00 I meant that Your new Screenshots folder might be inside `Pictures\subfolder\anothersubfolder\Screenshots`.

Comment: @Jaketr00 Use the search box of Pictures - enter "Screenshots" there.

Comment: I have manually gone through all the folders, and most of the folders under Pictures I made myself.  And I can't find any screenshot folder/any of my screenshots.

Comment: @Jaketr00 See another idea I edited into my answer.

Comment: the `Location` is set to the same directory as my screenshots folder right now.

Comment: @Jaketr00 You can change it to a different folder or click "restore default"  and see if that makes it start working again. But there is another option - see my new edit.

Comment: actually changing the location of the screenshots folder fixed it! If you change your answer to this ill up vote it, thank you

Comment: @Jaketr00 It's already in my (updated) answer - `...see a tab called "Location" ... that is your screenshots folder ... You can change it or "restore default". Maybe that will fix it.`.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part that said `change`, I only saw the `restore default`

Comment: @Jaketr00 I'm glad you got it fixed. (Now that I have enough reputation for upvoting, +1 for the question.)

Comment: But PrtSc is not a function key. Or is it treated as F13? Undocumented? Is it a Mac thing?

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 1 year ago"*. Perhaps somebody else can chime in?

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any reason Windows 10 won't let me screenshot?

It depends on the version of Windows 10 you are running. After the *[Creators Update](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_1703)*, Windows allows us to use <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> keystroke to take a screenshot of a selected part of the screen.

This is my favorite method as I can select the portion I want. It does not require any image editing tool to crop/resize the screenshot after capture.

If you are on a laptop or your keyboard has different layout, with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, then you should press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

> Where are all the screenshot stored?

By default, all captured screenshot are stored in the *Pictures* → *Screenshots* folder.

> Is there any reason Windows 10 won't let me screenshot?

If you have installed a third-party software to help you take screenshots, this software may take over the [<kbd>Print Screen</kbd>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Print_Screen) key that makes the default screen capture function of Windows doesn't work as expected.

Windows has redesigned the *Snip & Sketch* tool and make it more effective to capture screenshot. In fact, it gradually replaced *Snipping Tool* and the default screenshot function of Windows.

> How to restore the default location of the Screenshots folder?

Access the *Properties* of the current screenshot folder, navigate to the the *Location* tab and click on the the <kbd>Restore Default</kbd> button. By doing this, the location of where your screenshots store will be restored to the default, which is *Pictures* → *Screenshots*. I have got a few issues when capturing screenshots on Windows and use this to get rid of it.

If the issue persists, I would recommend upgrading your Windows 10 to the latest version and try out the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> keystroke.

Source: [How To Take A Screenshot On Windows 10 Computer](https://bytebitebit.com/1572/how-to-take-a-screenshot-on-windows-10/)

Answer (score 2):

I also lost the screenshots folder under the 'Pictures' folder in [Windows 10 Home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_editions#Base_editions). This issue is found when I check the registry settings.

During when I lost the folder, I opened the registry by typing "regedt32.exe" and search for:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`

Now after clicking on user shell folders, see the right side panel, where it shows under the name {B7BEDE81-DF94-4682-A7D8-57A52620B86F} under data %USERPROFILE%\Pictures\Screenshots

Note: if the data value is this then it means you have a screenshots folder, but when the screenshots folder is missing, the reason may be sometimes when we save over screenshots to an external hard drive then we cut the original screenshots folder under the 'Pictures' folder.

Note: when you do this mistake, after that, if checking your registry, check it under the name {B7BEDE81-DF94-4682-A7D8-57A52620B86F} under data.

Note: this time under data: {here the path will show where you save the 'Screenshots' folder}.

Note: if you want everything back to normal then you just have to find you folder where you have saved then cut and past it to its actual location under the 'Pictures' folder.

Then everything gets back to normal and your data: here is the actual path that will be shown of your screenshots, like this: "%USERPROFILE%\Pictures\Screenshots"

Comment: I've fixed the path and rebooted to make it work. No D:\pics\Screenshots needed in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue on my Surface Pro 2, and brought it to a Microsoft Store to have them look at. I'm not sure what they did (and they didn't seem to, either), but while they were poking around it, the screenshots started saving in the `Pictures\Screenshots` folder again.

My guess is that the process of installing Windows 10 had reset the index of which screenshot it was on, and since there was already one (or many) with the same name (`"Screenshot #.png"`) in the folder, it opted to not save rather than overwrite or increment its index. Unfortunately, I can't validate this guess since the problem doesn't occur on my machine, anymore. Perhaps you could look into changing the registry value for `ScreenshotIndex` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`. Try setting it higher than the highest numbered screenshot in your `Pictures\Screenshots` folder.

Answer (score 1):

I use a free third-party called [GreenShot](https://getgreenshot.org/) that will offer several options when it comes to taking screenshots via the PrintScreen key (customizable).

Free, as in free beer. And very convenient.

Comment: It's GPL, so free as in speech.